# AWS Elasticbeanstalk multi container - How to give a different filename other than "Dockerrun.aws.json" for deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can i give a different filename other than "Dockerrun.aws.json" for elastic beanstalk multi container deployment ?

I have different branches for different environments & they all should be in sync while releasing. For deploying in PROD i need to give a different ECR repo name to the JSON file.

Is there any way i can give a file as an input such as -
  `eb deploy -f Dockerrun.aws-prod.json` ?

PS - Environment variables are an option but is there any other straight forward option.